# Long server Loading nginx Joomla

Tags: nginx, joomla

Sometimes the server is taking way too long to respond
Waiting (TTFB) 30 sec on more
here is ngnix server settings. Did I install something incorrectly?

```
server {
        server_name pitamyshawarma.com www.pitamyshawarma.com
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

        root /var/www/pitamyshawarma.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
        # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # deny running scripts inside writable directories
        location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
                return 403;
                error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_cache phpcache; # The name of the cache key-zone to use
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30m; # What to cache: 'Code 200' responses, for half an hour
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; # What to cache: only GET and HEAD requests (not POST)
        add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status; # Add header so we can see if the cache hits or misses


         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;


        }


        # caching of files 
        location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
                expires 1y;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
                expires 14d;
        }


    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
```

*** bunch of ssl staff here

```
}

server {
    if ($host = www.pitamyshawarma.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = pitamyshawarma.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name pitamyshawarma.com www.pitamyshawarma.com
        server_name_in_redirect off;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```